# Is there a way to export a textView to a Pages document?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created an iPhone app that can export the contents of a textView to email, to text message and I also want to be able to export the data to a Pages document on my phone.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know pages is a protected format by Apple. They have not released the specifications and there are no inbuilt functions within xcode to support that. So, no easy way unfortunately.

If you want some proposed solutions for saving as an rtf on iPhone:
[How to create and save a .rtf, .doc, .docx in Objective-C for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235532/how-to-create-and-save-a-rtf-doc-docx-in-objective-c-for-ios)